# Ignore paths during next build

Tags: web, webpack, next.js, bundling-and-minification

I work with a huge monorepo. The production build for our next app takes about 20 minutes. I am trying bring this number down.

**Issue**: I was exploring `module.noParse` callback exposed by webpack and noticed that during the build for server and client, not only the source files, but the mock json files, test utils and story files were being read. This happens twice(server & client). This was expected. There are some libs which export mocks and other files which are used by some other libraries.

In my opinion, resolving and reading files is one of costliest operations during a build step. I am trying to check if there is a way we can avoid reading these files during the build. Here is what I have tried so far:

> "next": "12.3.4"

- Add `ignore-loader` to the webpack config - this does not work for me because the index file which was originally exporting the mock json files, test utils and story files errors out - `Module not found: Can't resolve 'ignore-loader' in '/path/to/my/app'`

  ```
  webpackConfig.module.rules?.push({
      test: /stories|tests|mocks/,
      loader: "ignore-loader",
  });
  ```
- Tried adding `config.module.rules[x].exclude = /stories|tests|mocks/;` - But this does not exclude the files I want to ignore

Am I on the right path here? I have spent a considerable amount of time trying to figure this out without any success.

Comment: Can you explain more on "huge monorepo"? The monorepo itself won't cause the Webpack performance issues. Also, modifying Webpack configuration with Next is not exactly easy. There is lots that goes into it and generally a bad idea to change is due to shear number of things it has to take care - SSR, CSR, ISR, etc. But in general you should explore combination of `cache`, `DllPlugin`, etc. Also consider using SWC instead of Babel if not already doing it. Next supports it.